# How can I remove all elements matching an xpath in python using lxml?

Tags: python, lxml

So I have some XML like this:

```
<bar>
  <foo>Something</foo>
  <baz>
     <foo>Hello</foo>
     <zap>Another</zap>
  <baz>
<bar>
```

And I want to remove all the foo nodes. Something like this doesn't work

```
params = xml.xpath('//foo')
for n in params:
  xml.getroot().remove(n)
```

Giving

```
ValueError: Element is not a child of this node.
```

What is a neat way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try:

```
 for elem in xml.xpath( '//foo' ) :
      elem.getparent().remove(elem)
```

remove it from it's parent, not the root 
( unless it IS a child of the root element )